# WordPress: get queried object method always return null

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working a CMS based WordPress project and need some customization for search I mean custom search and for the `terms` I need `get_queried_object` and I have used like below

search.php

```
$object = get_queried_object();
var_dump($object);
// NULL
```

**Edit search.php**

I need `terms` from that query like below to use

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($object->slug)
        )
    )
);
```

I have tried [this from SO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128685/get-queried-object-returns-null-on-post-date-archive) but result is the same, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to get on that query ??

Comment: I need `terms` from that query @developerme

Comment: Please show me your full code?In which file you write this code?

Comment: @developerme edited question that is my code after getting `terms` then I will move forward

Comment: Have you tried adding `wp_reset_query();` before the `$object = get_queried_object();`?

Comment: @Sally tried and result is same

Comment: are you added this query in search.php file?

Comment: Yes, this added to search.php file @developerme

Comment: I didn't notice it's on the search results page, where on that page, by default, `WP_Query::$queried_object` is indeed a `null` unless you or a plugin modifies it. Did you mean to use `get_search_query()` instead, which is the current search query/keyword? I mean, you might want to try `'terms' => array( get_search_query() )`.

Comment: Yes! exactly @Sally this working, Thanks

Comment: @Sally you want to post this an answer? you can this

Comment: @IMPD-INC Yes, actually! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As discussed via the comments;) Use the `get_search_query()` function and not `get_queried_object()`, which always returns `null` on the search results page.

So here's the full code:

```
$search_term = get_search_query(); // The current search query/keyword.
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $search_term )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need some customization for search, do utilize `get_search_query()` function instead.